# Flutter Firebase Authentication problems with loading next page

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, flutter-dependencies

I am making a login page wherein I have authenticated the users but I cannot go to the next page automatically unless I hit the back button on my login page and here are a few warnings I am getting.

Here is my main.dart

```
Future main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  // start: firebase initialization for app
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  // end

  // start: run the actual app through MaterialApp()
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
// end

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: StreamBuilder(
      // initialData: ,
      stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          return const BottomNavBar();
        } else {
          return const LandingPage();
        }
      },
    ));
  }
}
```

Here is my login page code:

```
class LoginMember extends StatefulWidget {
  const LoginMember({super.key});

  @override
  State<LoginMember> createState() => _LoginMemberState();
}

class _LoginMemberState extends State<LoginMember> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  String email = "";
  String password = "";
  bool login = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: SafeArea(
        // to fix renderBox problem
        child: ListView(
          children: [
            Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                // back button on top
                IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.pop(context);
                  },
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back_rounded),
                  splashRadius: 20,
                ),
                Center(
                  // login page image
                  child: Image.asset(
                    "assets/login.png",
                  ),
                ),
                const Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 6.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                  // login heading
                  child: Text(
                    "Login",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                      fontSize: 25.0,
                      letterSpacing: 0.5,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                // user id text feild
                Form(
                  key: _formKey,
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Padding(
                        padding:
                            const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(17.0, 23.0, 17.0, 14.0),
                        child: TextFormField(
                          key: ValueKey(email),
                          validator: (value) {
                            if (value!.isEmpty || !value.contains('@')) {
                              return 'Please enter valid email!';
                            } else {
                              return null;
                            }
                          },
                          decoration: const InputDecoration(
                            prefixIcon: Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0),
                              child: Icon(
                                Icons.mail,
                                size: 23.0,
                              ),
                            ),
                            border: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderRadius:
                                  BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(30.0)),
                            ),
                            labelText: "Mail ID",
                            floatingLabelStyle: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 21.0,
                            ),
                          ),
                          onSaved: (value) {
                            setState(() {
                              email = value!;
                            });
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                      // password text feild
                      Padding(
                        padding:
                            const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(17.0, 0.5, 17.0, 16.0),
                        child: TextFormField(
                          key: ValueKey(email),
                          validator: (value) {
                            if (value!.length < 6) {
                              return 'Please enter valid password!';
                            } else {
                              return null;
                            }
                          },
                          obscureText: true,
                          decoration: const InputDecoration(
                            prefixIcon: Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0),
                              child: Icon(
                                Icons.key,
                                size: 23.0,
                              ),
                            ),
                            border: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderRadius:
                                  BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(30.0)),
                            ),
                            labelText: "Password",
                            floatingLabelStyle: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 21.0,
                            ),
                          ),
                          onSaved: (value) {
                            setState(() {
                              password = value!;
                            });
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                      // login elevated button
                      Center(
                        child: ElevatedButton(
                          onPressed: () async {
                            if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                              _formKey.currentState!.save();
                              AuthServices.signinUser(email, password, context);
                            }
                          },
                          style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                            backgroundColor: const Color(0xff337ccf),
                          ),
                          child: const Padding(
                            padding:
                                EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 10.0, 20.0, 10.0),
                            child: Text(
                              "Login",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 18.0,
                                letterSpacing: 0.5,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here are the warnings i am getting:

```
I/FirebaseAuth( 9875): Logging in as siddhi.patil211@vit.edu with empty reCAPTCHA token
W/System  ( 9875): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
D/TrafficStats( 9875): tagSocket(188) with statsTag=0xffffffff, statsUid=-1
W/System  ( 9875): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
D/FirebaseAuth( 9875): Notifying id token listeners about user ( putHmC9br6Zg6S210hndemi6XLs2 ).
D/FirebaseAuth( 9875): Notifying auth state listeners about user ( putHmC9br6Zg6S210hndemi6XLs2 ).
```

I cant really find the solution on this.

Comment: Try converting your login page to a stateless widget.